# How to calculate median while ignoring negative values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
y
-1
-1
2
3
2
1
0
```

I need to apply a rolling window of 3 and calculate a median, while ignoring negative (e.g. `-1`) values. How can  I do so?

This is what I tried:

```
window = 3
y.rolling(window)[y>=0].apply(lambda x: np.median(x)).dropna()
```

Comment: What's the issue, do you get an error  ?

Comment: Try: `df[df.y>=0].rolling(3).median()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter in lambda function or filter before, but output is different

```
window = 3
df['new1'] = df.y.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.median([x>=0]), raw=False)
df['new2'] = df.loc[df.y>=0, 'y'].rolling(3).median()
print (df)
   y  new1  new2
0 -1   NaN   NaN
1 -1   NaN   NaN
2  2   0.0   NaN
3  3   1.0   NaN
4 -2   1.0   NaN
5 -1   0.0   NaN
6  0   0.0   2.0
```